# javascript check on undefined to prevent app break

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

often time I missed one or two checking thus it break the entire app. I really feel this is a pain in writing in js because one simple mistake can ruin entire app.

Take this code

```
{this.state.floor && this.state.floor[this.state.selectedTab].units.length === 0 && <div>render something</div>}
```

it will have error if units is undefined. How to I check? the first check `this.state.floor` doesn't seem to work. Should I check if `this.state.floor.length > 1`?

If the return of data has nested or multiple nested properties, my jsx will be so complicated sometime.

Comment: Beside `this.state.floor` you'll also have to check if `this.state.floor[this.state.selectedTab]` and `this.state.floor[this.state.selectedTab].units` exist.

Comment: @Titus that's why I said, checking make my jsx look so messy, any solution to this problem?

Comment: Not really, you can extract the check into its own function like TLadd proposed or create a utility function that makes checking for properties easer (eg: `Utils.hasProp(obj, "prop1.prop2....")`) but you'll have to do the check if you're not sure that the properties are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with lodash `get` function like this :

```
const r = {a:{b:{name:'foo'}}};

const existence = !!_.get(r, 'a.b.name');// !! Convert to the returned value to boolean 

console.log(existence); // true
```

has you can see the `_.get` secound parameter can be property path like `'a.b.name'`

in your case i would do:

```
!!_.get(this.state, `floor[${this.state.selectedTab}].units.length`);
```

Comment: I know get of lodash, it's the best approach for me also now, but the `!!` is needed?

Comment: I know get of lodash, it's the best approach for me also now, but the `!!` is needed?

Comment: the double exclamation mark is not needed, you can use the returned value as well inside if.

Answer (score 0):

If the logic to determine whether I should render something or not gets complicated, I will usually extract it to a function rather than leaving it all in the main render's jsx.

```
renderSomething() {
  const { floor, selectedTab } = this.state
  if (floor && floor[selectedTab] && floor[selectedTab].units && floor[selectedTab].units.length === 0) {
    return <div>render something</div>
  }
  return null
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {renderSomething()}
      {renderSomethingElse()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you can't assume anything about your state, the above check ought to be safe. Usually, you may be able to assume some things about your state if you are the one controlling the data that would make some of the checks unnecessary. For instance, you may know that it is the case that every value in the floor object always has a units property. Thus, the `floor[selectedTab].units` would not be required. The extra check obviously doesn't hurt anything, but it can clutter code to always add what would often be redundant checks.

If you're feeling pain keeping track of what values may be undefined and do need extra safety checks, I'd definitely recommend using [flow](https://flow.org/) or [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). Let the computer do a lot of that bookkeeping.

Answer (score 0):

use this function for arrays or nested array (but not for strings)

```
arr={nested:{nested2:{val:'isset'}}}

if(t=isset(arr,'nested=>nested2=>val')){
    alert(t)
}
function isset(obj,nested) {
    var dub=obj
    var isset=false
    if(typeof(obj)!="undefined" && typeof(nested)!="undefined"){
        var arr=nested.split('=>');
        for(var k in arr){
            var key=arr[k];
            if(typeof(dub[key])=="undefined"){
                isset=false;
                break;
            }
            dub=dub[key];
      isset=dub
        }   
    }
    
    return isset;
}
```